# App store application package name

Tags: app-store

If I have an application ID for an app on the iOS App Store, how can I find the package name?

For example, if I know the application ID is 457446957, how can I find out what app this is (Jetpack Joyride, in this case):

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jetpack-joyride/id457446957?mt=8&isWebExpV2=true&dataOnly=true

Comment: I think you actually mean bundle id 
(package name is what it's called in Google Play store)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Return all information about application(include package name)

> https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually need the package name to load an App Store page, just the ID. So for your above example, if you load:

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id457446957

you'll get the App Store page for that app and could grab the package name using web-scraping. In this example,

```
h1.product-header__title product-header__title--app-header
```

contains the text:

```
Jetpack Joyride
```

Comment: I need package name not for load app store page =)